# Saving values as views on a page(post) for users that are not logged in?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to keep track of how many people viewed a post, for a logged users is easy since every user has a unique `user_id` and every post has a unique `post_id` i can just save every view as a row with the `user_id` and the `post_id` `COUNT` them and show them back to the page as views. But how do i keep track of views for a non logged user since saving their `IP` or using a `Cookie` is not reliable?

Comment: One way is to use a session and generate a unique identifier for each visitor when they first come to your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `anonymous_id` for every users that are not logged in. If `anonymous_id` is not present in the session cookie, then you can assign a random, or auto-increment ID to that user.

Example implementation:

```
function getAnonymousId() {
    // get auto increment id from database
}

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['anonymous_id'])) {
    $_SESSION['anonymous_id'] = getAnonymousId();
}
```